# why slicing django queryset return a list

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a queryset derived from a piece of code, called objs. I print both type(objs) and type(objs[0:10]) in the same print function as follows:

```
print(type(objs), type(objs[0:10]))
```

The results show type(objs) is a queryset. The type(objs[0:10]) is a list

But when I lookup django document, the second one should also be a queryset. What are the possible reasons for this?

Answer (score 6):

[The Django docs say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated):

> Slicing a `QuerySet` that has been evaluated also returns a list.

If you slice an *unevaluated* `QuerySet`, then you'll get another `QuerySet` (as long as you don't use the "step" parameter of slice syntax).

Comment: I used | before to combine to queryset. will this evaluate the Queryset?

Comment: @baron, I'm not sure what you mean. Could you update your question to include your actual `QuerySet` code?

Comment: @tsritebm Thank you. The QuerySet code is long, and I do not know how to simplify it. Is that a way to test if the queryset has been evaluated or not?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Just check if you do any of the following with the `QuerySet`: iteration (e.g., for loops), pickle, cache, `repr()`, `len()`, `list()`, or `bool()`. Check out [When QuerySets are evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

Comment: The scenario I got the queryset is as follows: I got one row from Table A, called QuerySetA. I then get related rows from Table B called QuerySetB, since there is one to many relationship. Because the QuerySetB is so large that when I use QuerySetB.values_list('field1', flat = 'True') to get the whole list of field1, I got ERROR: stack depth limit exceeded. So I consider to slice QuerySetB into several small queryset, and use values_list on these small querysets. I tried slice, but this return a list. I also tried Panigator to divide QuerySetB to pages, but it also returns a list.

Comment: Calling `values_list` will evaluate the `QuerySet`, but it sounds like you aren't using that command right now because of the error.

I really don't know what to say without seeing the code. Someone else might be able to discern what the problem is based on your description, but I'm not able to.

Comment: For those who TIL it today, as I did. If I slice in Django shell I get a QuerySet. But if I do it with debugger from within the running process I get a `list`.